# Function returning exception instead of throwing

Tags: java, validation, java-8, exception, runtimeexception

Is it good practice to define function in such a way that instead of throwing, it returns a exception?

e.g.
Just to avoid early initialization of exception object, I'm passing a function which owns the responsibility to build and return exception if condition satisfied.

I've defined my validator having this method

```
static <T> Validator<T> validator(Predicate<T> predicate, Function<T, RuntimeException> execGen)
```

and `validate` method implementation like:

```
{
  if(!predicate.test(data))
  {
    throw execGen.apply(data);
  }
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: no, it's nonsense. An exception should be something that breaks the flow, not a part of the flow

Comment: Would be useful if you share more code on how this is being called in different scenarios. Also, where is “data” coming from?

Comment: That looks fine to me. It's basically similar to Optional.orElseThrow(), which expects a Supplier<Throwable>, and calls it to get and then throw the exception in case the optional is empty.

Comment: @Stultuske Conceptually I agree with you. But what if I a have situation where catch block is huge enough to be exported as a function. Shouldn't in that scenario we must define a function which return an exception?

Comment: @Arun either your catch block handles the exception (which means there won't be one to return), or you propagate your exception, meaning in most cases (unless you want to add some specific logging) you won't even need a try-catch, or you just build a new Exception and throw that. if that is so much business you would need a seperate method for it ... besides, if you do want to build an Exception to throw in another method, just throw it from there

Comment: @Stultuske quite insightful, having function which throws Runtime exception instead of return will be better way to achieve same. Thanks

Comment: @Stultuske except that there is no way to tell the java compiler that a method/function will throw unconditionally, hence, the compiler will require you to provide a valid code path (including returning a value when the method is not `void`), despite you know that this is dead code. As said by JB Nizet, the JDK uses the concept of an exception supplier itself.

Comment: @Holger public void whatEver() { throw new Exception(); } you think this won't throw an Exception? the case is: the method will not be called, unless in a catch block, to build the Exception that has to be thrown. so, either you do: public Exception whatEver()... throw(whatEver()); or you just throw the Exception from whatEver. I recommend not creating a 'whatEver' at all, but, in case you do want to, you can just as easily throw it from there, instead of returning it

Comment: @Stultuske the *compiler* does not know that `whatEver()` will throw unconditionally and requires you to have a valid code flow after calling `whatEver()`, e.g. having a return or throw statement or initialize the variables used in the other branch. Even worse, the compiler is right, someone *could* change the method to return normally, without anyone noticing. A method supposed to return the exception can not return without returning it. The only thing it could do, is returning `null`, which you would notice immediately due to the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Holger which is one of the reasons why my point is: why create a method?

Comment: @Stultuske for example, to allow the caller to determine the (possibly checked) exception type. The actual example of `Optional.orElseThrow()` has been mentioned already. If the type is fixed, you may use a supplier for the message instead, like with `Objects.requireNonNull`. But generally, moving the exception construction into a new method makes the normal flow more readable and may improve the performance. Which is the reason why all of JDK’s collection classes, NIO buffers, and `java.util.Objects` use this pattern internally. E.g., check what `Objects.checkIndex(-1, 0);` will do…

Comment: @Holger for your first example are you saying that something like this `public String test(String input) throws IOException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(input)
                       .orElseThrow(IOException::new);
    }` will tell the caller what type of Exception might be thrown without actually throwing it? isn't what the `throws IOException` part is for? can you expand that part of the comment may be? thank you

Comment: @Eugene in your example, the caller of `orElseThrow` tells it to throw the checked exception `IOException`. If you want `SQLException` instead, go ahead, no problem. How could `orElseThrow` throw precisely the exception you want, without accepting a factory for it?